QGLViewer external symbol not resolved when switching to MSVC
I am migrating a project from MInGW to MSVC, originaly it was a Qt Creator project. I have imported the project to Visual Studio and after linking all the static librairies, verified the version etc, I get an error at compilation in the .obj files as follow :
LNK2001 symbole externe non résolu "private: static class QList<class QGLViewer *> QGLViewer::QGLViewerPool_" (?QGLViewerPool_@QGLViewer@@0V?$QList@PEAVQGLViewer@@@@A) MoProViewer2    E:\crm2\moproviewer-msvc\Interface.obj  

I had the same error before, (5972 errors to be exact) and after adding the library libQGLViewer2.lib to the linker etc it went down to 188 of these error messages. I have checked I should have the right version that I built myself using MSVC but now I dont know what to do to resolve these missing external symbols.

Was all the dependent libraries and everything recompiled using msvc? Remember that you can't mix compilers when it comes to c++ based code.

@drescherjm Yes, everything should be recompiled, all the libraries etc. I am not the one who created this, I just got working on it but as fars I am concerned everything has been recompiled with MSVC 2019. Yes 2019 because the project uses Qt 5.15.2 which only comes with an MSVC 2019 version
